# Socket operation on non-socket, zmq options

Tags: c++, sockets, zeromq

Whenever I am trying to set socket options in zmq I get `Socket operation on non-socket`.

```
zmq::socket_t socket = new zmq::socket_t(*context,ZMQ_REP);
int64_t t = 1000;
socket->setsockopt(ZMQ_RCVTIMEO,&t,sizeof(t));
socket->bind("ipc:///tmp/zmqsocket");
```

Can someone tell me what am I doing wrong?

I am using ZeroMQ 4.0.4 with c++ binding.

Edit: Tried setting the option before/after binding, nothing changed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use the correct type for ZMQ_RCVTIMEO option, it use an int (not int64).

From zmq documentation [zmq-setsockopt](http://api.zeromq.org/3-0:zmq-setsockopt)

```
ZMQ_RCVTIMEO: Maximum time before a recv operation returns with EAGAIN

Sets the timeout for receive operation on the socket. If the value is 0, zmq_recv(3) will return immediately, with a EAGAIN error if there is no message to receive. If the value is -1, it will block until a message is available. For all other values, it will wait for a message for that amount of time before returning with an EAGAIN error.
Option value type   int
Option value unit   milliseconds
Default value   -1 (infinite)
Applicable socket types     all
```

Then the following code is working :

```
zmq::context_t context(1);
zmq::socket_t socket(context,ZMQ_REP);
int t = 1000;
socket.bind("ipc:///tmp/zmqsocket");
socket.setsockopt(ZMQ_RCVTIMEO,&t,sizeof(t));
```

Answer (score 1):

### Remember a Rule of Thumb since API v2.1

As far as in v2.1, the **`setsockopt()` manpage warning** says:

```
     int zmq_setsockopt ( void       *socket,
                          int         option_name,
                          const void *option_value,
                          size_t      option_len
                          );
     Caution: All options,
              with the exception of ZMQ_SUBSCRIBE,    ZMQ_UNSUBSCRIBE,
                                    ZMQ_LINGER,       ZMQ_ROUTER_MANDATORY,
                                    ZMQ_PROBE_ROUTER, ZMQ_XPUB_VERBOSE,
                                    ZMQ_REQ_CORRELATE,
                                and ZMQ_REQ_RELAXED,
              only take effect for subsequent socket bind/connects.
              ^^^^                 ^^^^^^^^^^
```

A code that aspires to be compatible with the published ZeroMQ API shall call `.setsockopt()` to set the **ZMQ_RCVTIMEO *before*** going to `.connect()` / `.bind()`

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. The order of API calls still matters. Keep isolation steps for the issue tracing. What have you tested so far to isolate the root-cause -- **in which exact point** of the code the error is fired? Upon .bind(), upon .setsockopt()? What O/S does your app rely on -- Win, Linux and how was your /tmp/zmqsocket entity preconfigured there?